# Problem of Number Theory

Tags: number-theory

Can you give a tip for this question?

For all $ n $ odd positive integer, let be

$ F(n) = \# \{ a($mod $ n): a^{n-1} \equiv 1($mod $n) \} $

that is the number of elements of the set.

- Show that
  $$ F(n) = \prod_{p|n} gcd(p-1,n-1) $$
- Let be $ F_0(n) $ the numbers $ a($mod $n) $ such that $ a^n \equiv a($mod $n) $. Find a formula like the previous one,
- Show that if $ F_0(n) $ < n, then $ F_0(n) \leq \frac{2}{3} n $. Show that if $ n \neq 6 $ and $ F_0(n) < n $ then $ F_0(n) \leq \frac{3}{5} n $

Comment: A number $a$ such that $a^{n-1}$ is *not* congruent to 1 (modulo $n$) is called a *witness* to the compositeness of $n$. For some purposes, it is necessary to get a lower bound on the number of witnesses (which implies an upper bound on your $F(n)$). There is a fair amount of literature on that topic, so I suggest a web search for some of the keywords I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I have skimmed over some steps; you can try filling in the details.

1) Write $n=\prod_{i=1}^{m}{p_i^{a_i}}$, where $p_i$ are odd primes.

2) There exists a primitive root $\pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$.

3) Using 2), conclude that the number of solutions $\pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$ of $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p_i^{a_i}}$ is $\gcd(\varphi(p_i^{a_i}), k)$.

4) Apply 4) for $k=n-1$ and Chinese Remainder Theorem to get $F(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{m}{\gcd(\varphi(p_i^{a_i}), n-1)}=\prod_{p\mid n}{\gcd(p-1, n-1)}$.

5) If we want to look at even $n$, then for $2^l \| n$, we get $F(n)=\alpha\prod_{p\mid n, 2 \nmid p}{\left(\gcd(p-1, n-1) \right)}$. where $\alpha$ is the number of solutions to $a^{n-1} \equiv 1\pmod {2^l}$. We get $a \equiv 1 \pmod{2^l}$. Thus $$F(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}{\left(\gcd(p-1, n-1) \right)}$$

---

For $F_0(n)$, a similar approach applies and we get $\gcd(\varphi(p_i^{a_i}), k)+1$ solutions in step $3$, so $$F_0(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}{\left(\gcd(p-1, n-1)+1 \right)}$$ The analysis of even $n$ is also similar, and we get the same formula.

---

Note $\gcd(p-1, n-1)+1 \leq p$ so $F_0(n) \leq \prod_{p \mid n}{p} \leq n$. If there is strict inequality, either $n$ is not squarefree or $\gcd(p-1, n-1)<p-1$ for some $p$.

In the former, if $q^2 \mid n$, $F_0(n) \leq \prod_{p \mid n}{p} \leq \frac{n}{q} \leq \frac{n}{2}$.

In the latter case clearly $p>2$, and we have $\gcd(p-1, n-1) \leq \frac{p-1}{2}$ so $\gcd(p-1, n-1) \leq \frac{p+1}{2} \leq \frac{2}{3}p$. Thus $F_0(n) \leq \frac{2n}{3}$.

---

Note that if $n$ not squarefree or $p \geq 5$ in case 2, we get $F_0(n) \leq \frac{3n}{5}$. Thus if $\frac{3n}{5}<F_0(n)<n$ then we must have $n$ squarefree and $p=3$ in case $2$, $\gcd(3-1, n-1)=1$, $\gcd(p-1, n-1)=p-1$ for $p \mid n, p \not =3$.

We have $\gcd(2, n-1)=1$ so $2 \mid n$. Thus $6 \mid n$

If $p \mid n$ for some $p>3$ then $\gcd(p-1, n-1)=p-1$ implies $n$ odd, a contradiction.

Thus $n$ is squarefree and a multiple of $6$, i.e. $n=6$.